# Load @configuration based on property in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am learning spring batch, and trying to load job configuration based on some property. Is this possible, can we load @Configuration classes based on some property. If yes how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to use `@ConditionalOnProperty` in your `@Configuration` class as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = {"your-property-name"}, havingValue = "true")
public class ConditionalConfiguration {}
```

You can find more information in the following online resources:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty